# Descarga a Excel resultados de consulta SQL server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, excel, headers

podría apoyarme, tengo una consulta que me muestra el historial de un determinado cliente que se ingresa en un inputbox, en pantalla me muestra los resultados, ahora bien para exportar a Excel dichos resultados no me arroja nada de información.

este es parte del código de la consulta y que muestra correctamente los datos solicitados.

De antemano, les agradezco el apoyo. saludos y excelente dia.

Consultahist.php

```
<?php
require_once '../configuration/configuracion.php';
require_once '../connection/SPDO.php';

//inicia script para obtener datos

if( $conn ){

$msg_error = "";

    if (isset($_POST['txt_socio']) && !empty($_POST['txt_socio']) ){
        $txt_socio = $_POST['txt_socio'];
    }
    else {
        $msg_error = "No se ha especificado ningun socio.";
    }


if ($msg_error == ""){

//ventas/devoluciones
$sql1 = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Date],103) AS fecha, CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Time],108) AS hora, [Transaction No_] AS transaccion, [Receipt No_] AS ticket, [Item No_] AS id_producto,
[Variant Code] AS talla, [Quantity] AS cantidad, [Price] - [Discount Amount] AS precio
FROM [$franquicia\$Trans_ Sales Entry]
WHERE [Customer No_] = '$txt_socio' /*AND [Store No_] IN ('$num_tda','030') */
ORDER BY cast([date] as datetime) desc, [Time], [Item No_], [Variant Code]";

$result_sun =@sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1) or die("Error no se pudo executar query Serrat: sqlserver: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $nom_tda;?> -Historico de venta</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../informacion/css/stilo.css">
</head>
<body background="../images/Report.jpg">

<div class="menu">
<?php require_once 'menu_sales.php';?>
</div>
<div class="padre">
    <div class="fechas">
<form id="frm_ventas" method="post" action="ConsultaHistorico.php">
    <label for="id_txt_socio"><strong>Socio:&nbsp</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="txt_socio" id="id_txt_socio" placeholder="Ingrese N0 de Socio">
        <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btn_socio" value="-Buscar-">
</form>
<?php if ($msg_error == ""){ ?>
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong><font size="3">Historico, del socio </font><font color="blue" size="5">[<?php echo $txt_socio; ?>]</font></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="0">
                <tr bgcolor="#33E3FF"><td>Ventas</td></tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#FFB233"><td>Devoluciones</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p><a href="desc_consultahist.php"><strong>Descargar Info</strong></a></p>

    </div>
<br/>
<?php if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result_sun) || sqlsrv_has_rows($result_ca)){?>
<div class="cont_tabla">
    <table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" id="id_tabla">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tienda</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Transaccion</th>
                    <th>Ticket</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Talla</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            while ( $row_sun = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_sun, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
            if($row_sun['cantidad'] < 0){
                $bg = "#33E3FF";
            } else {
                $bg = "#FFB233";
            }
        ?>
            <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $bg;?>">
                <td align="center">CG008</td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['fecha'];?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['hora'];?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['transaccion'];?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['ticket'];?></td>
                <td align="left"><?php echo $row_sun['id_producto'];?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['talla'];?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo number_format($row_sun['cantidad'],0);?></td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row_sun['precio'],2);?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            }
            
        ?>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
    <?php 
        } 
        else{
            echo "No existen registros para el socio seleccionado.";
        }   
    ?>
    <br />
    <br/>
        <p><a href="../index.php">Inicio</a></p>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

y este codigo ocupo para generar el archivo en excel.
desc_consultahist.php

```
    <?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');   
    header("Content-Disposition:inline; filename=Consulta_Hist.xls");
    if(!isset($_SESSION['nivel']))
        session_start();
    ?>
    <?php
        $fechaOld= $_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"];
        $ahora = date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
        $tiempo_transcurrido = (strtotime($ahora)-strtotime($fechaOld));
    
        if($tiempo_transcurrido>= 600) { //comparamos el tiempo y verificamos si pasaron 10 minutos o más
            session_destroy(); // destruimos la sesión
            header("Location: ../login.php"); //enviamos al usuario a la página principal
    
        }else {       //sino, actualizo la fecha de la sesión
            $_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"] = $ahora;
        } 
    ?>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['nivel']) && !empty($_SESSION['nivel'])){
            $nivel = $_SESSION['nivel'];    
    ?>
    <?php
    require_once '../configuration/configuracion.php';
    require_once '../connection/SPDO.php';
    
    //aqui deberia recuperar el dato del N0 de socio para la consulta del historico
    $txt_socio=$_POST['txt_socio'];
    if(isset($_POST['txt_socio']))
    {
    if( $conn )
    {
    //ventas/devoluciones
    $sql1 = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Date],103) AS fecha, CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Time],108) AS hora, [Transaction No_] AS transaccion, [Receipt No_] AS ticket, [Item No_] AS id_producto,
    [Variant Code] AS talla, [Quantity] AS cantidad, [Price] - [Discount Amount] AS precio
    FROM [$franquicia\$Trans_ Sales Entry]
    WHERE [Customer No_] = '$txt_socio'
    ORDER BY cast([date] as datetime) desc, [Time], [Item No_], [Variant Code]";
    
    $result_sun =@sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1) or die("Error no se pudo executar query SUN: sqlserver: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }
    }
    ?>
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $nom_tda;?> -Historico de venta</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Consulta Historico de clientes Vtas/Devns<font color="red"></font></h1>
    <?php 
        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result_sun)) //|| sqlsrv_has_rows($result_ca))
    {?>
        <table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" id="id_tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tienda</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <th>Transaccion</th>
                        <th>Ticket</th>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Talla</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
                while ( $row_sun = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_sun, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
                if($row_sun['cantidad'] < 0){
                    $bg = "#33E3FF";
                } else {
                    $bg = "#FFB233";
                }
            ?>
                <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $bg;?>">
                    <td align="center">CG008</td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['fecha'];?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['hora'];?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['transaccion'];?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['ticket'];?></td>
                    <td align="left"><?php echo $row_sun['id_producto'];?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $row_sun['talla'];?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo number_format($row_sun['cantidad'],0);?></td>
                    <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row_sun['precio'],2);?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
                }   
            ?>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
    <?php 
    } 
    else{
        echo "No existen registros para el socio seleccionado.";
        }   
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php 
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($result_sun);
        
        }else{
         echo $msg_error;
        }
    ?

>
```

lo obtenido con la consulta de descarga es:
Warning: sqlsrv_has_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\webs\serrat\salesEntry\desc_consultahist.php on line 56
No existen registros para el socio seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

Hiciste seguimiento a la variable de $_POST['txt_socio'];?
Hice un reporte similar y me saltaba error por que no estaba enviando de manera correcta las variables, posiblemente te pase lo mismo al estar tratando de generar el excel con una etiqueta "a" enviando a otro archivo.
Te envio como construi el excel

Envie los datos con un form e inputs hidden con los datos de la consulta en tu caso enviar $txt_socio=$_POST['txt_socio']; en un hidden.

```
<form method="post" class="container-fluid" action="includes/ReporteExcel.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $_POST['piso'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="l" value="<?php echo $_POST['linea'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="m" value="<?php echo $_POST['modulo'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="generar_reportePLM" value="Descargar">
    </form>
```

Los recibo y valido solo el input

si existe generar_reportePLM abre if
// NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reporte'.$*POST['p'].'*'.$*POST['l'].'*'.$_POST['m'].'.csv"');

```
// SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
$salida=fopen('php://output', 'w');
// ENCABEZADOS
fputcsv($salida, array('ESTIBA', 'N_CAJA', 'Base_Envio', 'CAJA', 'ID_5', 'ID_4', 'ID_3', 'ID_2', 'ID_1', 'PISO', 'LINEA', 'MODULO', 'UBICACION', 'TIPO_CAJA', 'DETALLE_UBICACION', 'DESCRIPCION_DEPENDENCIA', 'ESTADO', 'CONTENIDO_CAJA', 'MYT_ECAT_ADMON_RECAUDO', 'UNIDAD_CONTENEDORA', 'NIVEL', 'CANTIDAD_UNIDADES', 'PROYECTO', 'DETALLE'),';');
// QUERY PARA CREAR EL REPORTE
$sql="SELECT * FROM Estanteria WHERE PISO='".$_POST['p']."' AND LINEA='".$_POST['l']."' AND MODULO='".$_POST['m']."';";//Almacenamos la consulta sql en una variable.
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );//Se realiza la conexion con la bd y se ejecuta la consulta.
while( $filaR = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {//APERTURA WHILE PARA MOSTRAR LOS REGISTROS
    fputcsv($salida, array( $filaR['ESTIBA'], 
                            $filaR['N_CAJA'], 
                            $filaR['BASE'], 
                            $filaR['CAJA'], 
                            $filaR['ID_5'], 
                            $filaR['ID_4'], 
                            $filaR['ID_3'], 
                            $filaR['ID_2'], 
                            $filaR['ID_1'], 
                            $filaR['PISO'], 
                            $filaR['LINEA'], 
                            $filaR['MODULO'], 
                            $filaR['UBICACION'], 
                            $filaR['TIPO_CAJA'], 
                            $filaR['DETALLE_UBICACION'], 
                            $filaR['DESCRIPCION_DEPENDENCIA'], 
                            $filaR['ESTADO'], 
                            $filaR['CONTENIDO_CAJA'], 
                            $filaR['MYT_ECAT_ADMON_RECAUDO'], 
                            $filaR['UNIDAD_CONTENEDORA'], 
                            $filaR['NIVEL'], 
                            $filaR['CANTIDAD_UNIDADES'], 
                            $filaR['PROYECTO'], 
                            $filaR['DETALLE']),';');
```

cierra if

Comment: Muchas gracias @Edison, deja hago prueba como lo indicas... te agradezco por el apoyo.

Saludos